# pc not posting after it randomly shut off

Tags: bios, post

This morning I turned my PC on and after logging in I noticed that the time is still the same from when I last turned it off. So I changed it back to normal and after clicking apply and closing the window, I went to go click start and it just shut off, and now it doesn't want to even post. All it does is turn on with the fans spinning not even a beep.

I tried to turn it on. It did nothing. Then eventually after 10 or so attempts, it beeped and posted. It entered bios and after clicking exit it shut off and now doesn't post.

I've tried the following:

- Clearing CMOS.
- changing clock battery
- rearranging ram (to slot 1 and 3 to 1 and 2)
- changed power supply
- taking the cpu out and checking the pins

I even tested to see if the cpu was getting power and I know it is indeed getting power as it slowly heats up.

Pc specs:

- CPU: i7-4770k (stock cpu cooler)
- Motherboard: Asus B85M-E
- Ram: Kingston kvr16n11s8 (16gb x 2 8gb sticks)
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 4600
- OS: Windows 10
- Drive: Samsung 840 evo and 2 2tb drives

If anyone knows how to fix this it would be very much appreciated as I need to get a college project finished with in 2 months.

I've had it for just over a month or 2 and It's second hand and was in good condition when I bought it.

Update: I left it over night then plugged it in, it turned on then it went to bios then screen went black then purple now it turns on then off straight after a few seconds

Update 2: now it won't turn on when pushing power button or shorting the power pins

Comment: You've tried resetting the BIOS yet?

Comment: I tried clearing the cmos to to affect

Comment: Do you have a dedicated video card? If so, it's possible that resetting cmos fixed the bios corruption, but also reset the initial video output device to the cpu's integrated acceleration (if any). Try plugging a monitor into the MB if possible. If that works, go to bios and set the initial graphics output device (see MB manual for the phrasing they used) to the real gpu and plug the monitor back into the gpu. Edit: also verify the spkr/buzzer is present and functional.

Comment: no dedicated gpu is installed, the buzzer is present and functional

Comment: Alright, next step is power diagnostic. Unplug everything not needed to get into bios. All hdds, nics, all externals except one keyboard and one monitor. If that works then one of the things you unplugged has a short and is probably dead. If it still doesn't boot, get a multimeter and stick it into an open molex power between yellow and black. If that reads significantly below 12v, you could have a short in something that's still plugged in, or a bad psu.

Comment: Note that I'm only listing the things you might be able to fix without a complete overhaul. At this point it's 90% irreparable damage to the MB. The slim chance that it's actually a fried psu or hdd is what I'm talking you towards, so when you get a new MB you can be more certain that that will fix it. Though if you happen to have a *compatible* spare MB laying around, it's worth a shot.

Comment: Nothing is plugged in except monitor still no post and updated question